# data representation for svm

Tags: svm, libsvm, feature-extraction, data-representation

I have a million files which includes free text. Each file has been assigned a code or number of codes. The codes can be assumed as categories. I have normalized the text by removing stop words. I am using scikit-learn libsvm to train the model to predict the files for the right code/s (category).

I have read and searched a lot but i couldn't understand how to represent my textual data into integers, since SVM or most machine learning tools use numerical values for learning.

I think i would need to find tf-idf for each term in the whole corpus. But still i am not sure how would that help me to convert my textual data into libsvm format.

any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not forced to use tf-idf.

To begin with follow this simple approach:

1. Select all distinct words in all your documents. This will be your vocabulary. Save it  in a file.
2. For each word in a specific document, replace it with the index of the word in your vocabulary file.
3. and also add the number of time the word appears in the document

---

### **Example:**

I have two documents (stop word removed, stemmed) :

> hello world

and

> hello sky sunny hello

**Step 1:** I generate the following vocabulary

```
hello
sky
sunny
world
```

---

**Step 2:**

I can represent my documents like this:

> 1 4

(because the word hello is in position 1 in the vocabulary and the word world is in position 4)
and

> 1 2 3 1

---

**Step 3:** I add the term frequency near each term and remove duplicates

> 1:1 4:1

(because the word hello appears 1 time in the document, and the word world appears 1 time)

and

> 1:2 2:1 3:1

---

If you add the class number in front of each line, you have a file in libsvm format:

```
1 1:1 4:1
2,3 1:2 2:1 3:1
```

Here the first document has class 1, and the second document has class 2 and 3.

In this example each word is associated with the term frequency. To use tf-idf you do the same but replace the tf by the computed tf-idf.